# Keyvault Stored Secrets for Azure Container Apps with RBAC auth from ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity, azure-container-apps

I feel like I'm stuck in a catch 22 with how Microsoft has implemented this functionality in the Container App templates.  The issue, it seems to me, is that is actually validates the secret access as part of the template deploment... which creates the issue of the Managed Identity (system) not actually yet existing since the app hasn't been created, thus no way to assign that identity RBAC to the Keyvault, thus validation failes.

Am I missing something here, or is the process really going to require 2 templates... 1 with no secret references, just to "create" the thing, and then a second to actually properly configure it now that the managed identity is availabe?

```
The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'configuration.secrets' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "mysecret-name": 
Unable to get value using Managed identity system for secret mysecret-name. Error: unable to fetch secret 'mysecret-name' using Managed identity 'system'';.
```

```json
"configuration": {
  "secrets": [
    {
      "name": "mysecret-name",
      "keyVaultUrl": "[concat('https://',variables('vaultname'),'.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret')]",
      "identity": "system"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [user-assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview#managed-identity-types) will solve your problem:

1. Create a user-assigned managed identity.
2. Grant KV secrets read permission to the identity.
3. Create the container app.

Using [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep), that would look like that:

key vault role assignment module:

```
// key-vault-role-assignment.bicep
param keyVaultName string
param principalId string
param principalType string = 'ServicePrincipal'
param roleIds array

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = [for roleId in roleIds: {
  name: guid(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, keyVaultName, roleId, principalId)
  scope: keyVault
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', roleId)
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}]
```

and your main template:

```
// main.bicep
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param identityName string
param keyVaultName string
param containerAppEnvName string
param containerAppName string

// Create the identity
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = {
  name: identityName
  location: location
}

// Grant KV RBAC to the identity
module kvRbac 'key-vault-role-assignment.bicep' = {
 name: '${identityName}-${keyVaultName}-rbac'
 params: {
  keyVaultName: keyVaultName
  principalId: identity.properties.principalId
  roleIds: [ '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6' ] // Key vault secret user
 }
}

// Create the container app env
resource containerAppEnv 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-05-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvName
  ...
}

// Create the container app and assigned the identity
resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-05-01' = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  dependsOn: [
    kvRbac
  ]
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    environmentId: containerAppEnv.id
    workloadProfileName: 'Consumption'
    configuration: {
      ...
      secrets: [
        {
          name: 'applicationinsights-connection-string'
          keyVaultUrl: 'https://${keyVaultName}${environment().suffixes.keyvaultDns}/secrets/mysecret'
          identity: identity.id
        }
      ]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Az CLI / Az Powershell supports natively bicep but you could always generate the related ARM template using `az bicep build`:

```
az bicep build --file main.bicep
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to do a nested deployment with the principalID as output to the main/master template, but i guess then yes, you do need "two" templates

ex:

```
output  webAppMSI string = webApp.identity.principalId
```

or use bicep modules, here is a good sample:

https://blog.johnfolberth.com/chicken-and-the-egg-how-to-handle-bicep-interdependencies/